# Ошибка работы snap в Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: ubuntu, localhost

При попытке установить что-нибудь с помощью snap у меня выдаёт вот такую ошибку:
error: cannot communicate with server: Post "http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello-world": dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
Кто знает, как это исправить? Нигде не смог найти ответа.
Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl unmask snapd.service
sudo systemctl enable snapd.service
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
```

если не поможет`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -yqq daemonize dbus-user-session fontconfig sudo daemonize /usr/bin/unshare --fork --pid --mount-proc /lib/systemd/systemd --system-unit=basic.target exec sudo nsenter -t $(pidof systemd) -a su - $LOGNAME`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе видно что проблема в том что ты добавил ссылку http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello-world в /run/snapd.socket попробуй удалить и попробуй еще раз на всякий случай пропиши reboot;)

Comment: Что бы удалить попробуй sudo nano /var/snapd.socket далее убери ссылку и нажми ctrl + s далее ctrl + x

Comment: Я просто установил Ubuntu, я ничего не писал. Кстати, файла snapd.socket нету - при выполнении твоей команды создаётся новый))

Comment: Попробуй переустановить snap

Comment: Не помогло. Возможно, пропущены какие-то зависимости при установке. Ставил через apt.